# How can I override a class scoped __declspec(dllexport) annotation on a per-member basis?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, visibility, elf

On ELF targets, if I have `class Foo` and I have given it `default` visibility via a declaration like `class __attribute__((visibiility("default"))) Foo`, I can then selectively exempt certain members of the class from having `default` visibility by annotating them explicitly with `__attribute__((visibility("hidden"))`. This can be useful for inline methods that should not form part of the ABI, so that if they are emitted when building the library defining `class Foo`, they are not exported, or for `private` members or types within `class Foo` that should also not form part of its ABI.

However, on Windows, there appears to be no means to achieve this. While an unadorned `class Foo` is automatically private to a DLL, once adorned as `class __declspec(dllexport) Foo`, the entire class is now `dllexport`, and there appears to be no associated annotation that can selectively override the `__dllexport` status of a specific member. Tagging the select "not for export" members as `__declspec(dllimport)` is clearly wrong.

Is there some other way to prevent the class scoped `__dllexport` from applying to certain class members and/or types?

To make this more concrete, what I would like to say, and can say, when using ELF annotations is:

```
class __attribute__((visibility("default"))) Foo {
public:
    Foo(); // OK, default visibility

    // Don't let inlines join the ABI
    __attribute__((visibility("hidden")) inline void something() { ... }

private:
    // Don't let private members join the ABI
    __attribute__((visibility("hidden")) void _internal();

    // Our pImpl type is also not part of the ABI.
    struct __attribute__((visibility("hidden")) pimpl;
};
```

But I can't form the same thing using the MSVC attributes:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Foo {
public:
    Foo(); // OK, dllexport'ed

    // Don't let inlines join the ABI, but how to say it?
    __declspec(???) inline void something() { ... }

private:
    // Don't let private members join the ABI, but how?
    __declspec(???) void _internal();

    // Our pImpl type is also not part of the ABI, but how?
    struct __declspec(???) pimpl;
};
```

In a real world implementation, I'd expect the variation between these to be hidden behind a macro.

Is there some `__declspec` that I'm overlooking that has the semantics of `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))` and can override the class scope application of `__declspec(dllexport)`?

Comment: fyi _"inline methods that should not form part of the ABI,"_ inline does not mean inline (unless you use compiler specific force-inline extensions). So they are part of the ABI, inline is not even a hint to most modern compilers.

Comment: Also if a public method of the class calls a private method (of the same class) and the public method is inlined in the client application; then the private method needs to be linker visible and forms part of the ABI.

Comment: @Richard Critten To your second comment, agree completely, but this is tractable - just don't inline those public methods that must call private members, and it hasn't come up in practice. To your first comment, I agree that inline is "not even a hint", to the compiler, but it does have effects on linking. Consider the effects of `-fvisibility-inlines-hidden` has on ELF platforms. My argument for inlines not forming part of the ABI rests on the idea that as long as the inline method simply delegates to ABI methods, it doesn't matter whether the client and the library diverge in meaning.

Comment: It is done the other way around, you *don't* export the class and instead of hiding you apply the attribute only on the members that you want exported.  But tends to cause trouble, you can't export the v-table that way.  A .def file is the other way to do it, not much joy either.  Exposing an interface-style declaration is always best.

Comment: @HansPassant - Right, and not just the vtable, but typeinfo, etc. And I worry about implicit things, like move assignment. I do want those exported, but I don't want to need to `=default` each of them, just so I can slap `__declspec` on them. The .def file way sounds truly awful, especially when you consider that changing calling convention, runtime library, etc., are ABI affecting and could seemingly result in different symbols for the .def file? Maybe not, I've never tried, but it sure sounds painful. It really feels like MSVC is missing a feature here, not that there is much hope of change.

Comment: According to MSDN documentation, `__declspec(dllexport)` exports only "all of the public data members and member functions in a class" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx , so it seems you don't have to worry about your private members being exported.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx#Anchor_4) gives an idea of how it can be done. Here's a sample.

DLL_declspec.h:

```
#if defined(BUILD_DLL)
   #define DLL_DECLSPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#else
   #define DLL_DECLSPEC __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

To export the whole class:

```
#include "DLL_declspec.h"

class DLL_DECLSPEC TestExport
{
   public:

      TestExport();

      ~TestExport();

      std::string getName();

      int getID();
};
```

To export only a few handpicked members of the class:

```
#include "DLL_declspec.h"

class TestExport
{
   public:

      DLL_DECLSPEC TestExport();

      DLL_DECLSPEC ~TestExport();

      DLL_DECLSPEC std::string getName();

      int getID();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I never did such a thing, however following [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx#Anchor_4) it should be possible.

You should not specify any `__declspec` on the class level, and only specify `__declspec(dllexport)` for the members you want.

Hope this help.